# How to store an NSObject class in Realm?

Tags: ios, realm

I'm integrating `Realm` into my app. I need to know how to store a `custom class` object in an `RLMObject subclass`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only properties allowed to be saved in Realm are, accoding to [the Documentation](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#supported-types):

> Realm supports the following property types: BOOL, bool, int,
>   NSInteger, long, long long, float, double, NSString, NSDate, NSData,
>   and NSNumber tagged with a specific type.

If you need to store another object (you're mentioning an instance of a custom class), the officially supported way to doing so is creating a subclass of RLMObject (assuming you're on Objective-C) and, inside a property in your parent object, create the reference, like mentioned an example in the docs:

```
#import <Realm/Realm.h>

@class Person;

// Dog model
@interface Dog : RLMObject
@property NSString *name;
@property Person   *owner;
@end
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Dog) // define RLMArray<Dog>

// Person model
@interface Person : RLMObject
@property NSString             *name;
@property NSDate               *birthdate;
@property RLMArray<Dog *><Dog> *dogs;
@end
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Person) // define RLMArray<Person>
```

In this example we have a property `owner` in the Dog model. I think that's what you're looking for.